# Reducing multiple images into one for visual product recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

I am trying to create an efficient visual recommendation system for real estate but I am running into difficulties regarding image processing.

Indeed, the 'products' in this instance are defined by multiple images: rooms, kitchen, bathrooms, etc... Together they represent a general 'feel' for the product; is it spacious? bright? cosy? luxurious?

To keep it simple and efficient, I'd like to 'merge' these images into a single one. These are my thoughts so far;

- I could blend them all on the alpha channel but the amount of pictures per product is variable, so a property with 10 picture will naturally look messier than a listing with 2 pictures.
- I could merge stripes from each images. But for the same reasons as above, the resulting image would be either of variable size or not 'serialized' in the sense that I would not be comparing apples to apples.
- Another way might be to reduce the images to a color palette for brightness and color similarities and compute the 'dead-space' to provide inferences for luxury and spaciousness.
- ??? Matrix factorization ???

How can I reduce n pictures into a single one without loosing the important features needed to compute similarities?